# Iterating through a tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, iteration

I'm trying to figure out how I can iterate in reverse, and forward through this, or atleast call a method in reverse.

Here is how it works.

Widgets have a std::vector of Widget* which are that control's children. The child vector is z ordered which means that child[0] is behind child[1] (in render order). Each control has a pointer to its parent except for the root (dummy) widget whos parent is NULL.

For my rendering, I need to sort of do a staircase sort of iteration (back to front) ex:

```
root->child[0];
root->child[0]->child[0];
root->child[0]->child[1];
root->child[1];
root->child[1]->child[0];
root->child[1]->child[1];
```

However to find which widget is under the mouse, I must do my point in rectangle test from front to back:

```
   root->child[9]->child[1];
    root->child[9]->child[0];
    root->child[9];
    root->child[8]->child[2];
    root->child[8]->child[1];
    root->child[8]->child[0];
    root->child[8];
```

What sort of iteration would I need to efficiently do the above 2 types of iterations? (back to front, front to back).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  There are no linked-lists here; you have `std::vector`s, which you can iterate over in either direction.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth but each std::vector has children which also have children, you cant access a certain child without iterating through a parent hence a linked list,

Comment: I think some type of recursion might be needed, like while (children.size() > 0)

Comment: These are essentially trees.  You can traverse the trees going depth-first to the left (visiting children with the smaller indices first) using pre-order traversal or the right (visiting children with the larger indicies first) using post-order traversal.  Should be easiest to implement recursively.

Comment: This isn't a linked-list, this is a tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward iteration:

```
void blah_forward(const Widget *p)
{
    p->do_something();
    std::for_each(p->children.begin(), p->children.end(), blah_forward);
}
```

Reverse iteration:

```
void blah_reverse(const Widget *p)
{
    std::for_each(p->children.rbegin(), p->children.rend(), blah_reverse);
    p->do_something();
}
```

(untested, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: But what if p has children, these only do the iteration, it would need to be recursive

Comment: The reverse would have to `do_something()` after traversing the children.  The results shown are in post-order.

Answer (score 0):

What you really have here is a tree with ordered children. And if I understand correctly, what you want to traverse them using [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) visiting the children in reverse order. So you just need some recursive function widgetUnderMouse(Widget*) that traverses the tree in the order you want and checks if the current widget is under the mouse. Something like this I think.

```
Widget* widgetUnderMouse(Widget* root)
{
    if (root->hasChildren) 
    {
        vector<Widget*>::reverse_iterator rit;
        for (rit = root->child.rbegin(); rit < root->child.rend(); ++rit)
        {
            if (isWidgetUnderMouse(*rit)
            {
                return widgetUnderMouse(*rit);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Where `isWidgetUnderMouse` returns true or false if the passed in widget is under the mouse

Comment: You don't want `unsigned` here.  This is exactly the sort of wheel-reinvention and subsequent bugginess that the STL algorithms were designed to avoid...