# Incrementing an iterator for a BST

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-search-tree

I'm kind of stumped as to how I could do this properly, but I need to be able to increment an iterator within a binary search tree class I'm implementing, that uses templates.

The structure of the iterator has a current node, as well as an integer defining its current position. The only problem I'm having is, when it does a `++Iter` operation, how should I determine whether or not it should go right or left?

Here's the header file for the entire class:

```
template < typename TComparable, typename TValue > 
    class SearchTree
    {
    public:
        class Iterator;
    private:
        struct Node;
        typedef typename Node TNode;
    public:
        SearchTree( void );
        ~SearchTree( void );
    public:
        TValue find( const TComparable& k );
        TValue find( int32_t index );
        TValue find( const Iterator& pIter );

        Iterator begin( void ) const;
        Iterator end( void ) const;

        void insert( const TComparable& k, const TValue& v );
        void insert( const Iterator& pIter );

        friend class Iterator;
        friend class TNode;
    private:
        int32_t mNodeCount;
        TNode* mRoot;
    public:
        class Iterator 
        {
        public:
            Iterator( void );
            Iterator( int32_t position );
            ~Iterator( void );
            inline TNode* operator->( void ) const 
            { return mCurrentNode; }
            void operator++( void );
            bool operator==( const Iterator& pIter );
            bool operator!=( const Iterator& pIter );
        private:
            int32_t getNumStepsLeftToLeaf( void );
            int32_t getNumStepsRightToLeaf( void );
            bool isLeafNode( const Node*& n );
            bool isInternalNode( const Node*& n );
        private:
            TNode* mCurrentNode;
            int32_t mIterPosition;
            friend class TNode;
        };
    private:
        struct Node
        {
        public:
            Node( void ) : mParent( NULL ), mLeftChild( NULL ), mRightChild( NULL )
            {}
            ~Node( void )
            {
                if ( mParent ) delete mParent;
                if ( mLeftChild ) delete mLeftChild;
                if ( mRightChild ) delete mRightChild;
            }
            int32_t index;
            TComparable Key;
            TValue Value;
            TNode* mParent;
            TNode* mLeftChild;
            TNode* mRightChild;
        };
    };
```

Note that I cannot use exceptions for this since I plan to port a lot of this code to the Android NDK, which I believe cannot use exceptions with STLport (which is what I will be using - GnuSTL is GPL'd, which means for what I'm doing (which is for profit) I can't use it - if anyone has anything to contradict that, please let me know)

Also, before anyone mentions boost, I have already tried porting that to the NDK without success. I'd like to use that, as that would make life a lot easier, but for now I'm willing to write my own data structures and algorithms.

As far as the iterator, I'm guessing I'm missing something in my design here, and if anyone knows what this could be, please let me know. I'd be happy to post source for the entire class for this as well if anyone requires it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946876/iterating-through-a-tree

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at that one. It helped, but not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the prefix increment operator has this signature:

```
Iterator& operator++();
```

and the postfix should be declared and defined in terms of the prefix in this way:

```
const Iterator& operator++(int){Iterator old = *this; ++(*this); return old;}
```

You probably want the prefix to ask to its node the next (leftmost) node,

```
Iterator& Iterator::operator++(){
    myParent = mCurrentNode; 
    return  myParent.getRightOf(mCurrentNode); 
}
```

You see that I assumed you have a way to construct an iterator from a node you probably should have at least a 
private one.

I suppose you want to iterate through leaf nodes, (anyway the internal nodes implementation is not dissimilar). 
You need a getRightOf method more or less doing the following, let me write down some pseudocode for it:

```
Node* Node::getRightOf(Node* aNode){ 
    if aNode == mLeftChild{
        if mRightNode
            return mRightNode(this); 
        return mParent(this)
    }
    if aNode == mRightChild{
        return mParent(this)
    }
    if aNode == mParent{
        if mLeftNode
            return mLeftNode(this); 
        if mRightNode
            return mRightNode(this); 
        return this; 
    }
}
```

you need some care for managing cases like iterations at the end of the container.

**WARNING**

In Node's destructor I read:

```
if ( mParent ) delete mParent;
```

this looks dangerous: who deletes the ParentNode? The left or the right child?